# Can you fuse Anti-matter nuclei?

Tags: nuclear-physics, antimatter, fusion

I know that this is a simple question, but I could not for the life of me find a source that explains fusion for Anti-matter nuclei. intuitively, I can say that there shouldn't be any barrier for fusion of anti-matter nuclei since they have the same structure as nuclei. Given a large enough anti-hydrogen gas cloud, secluded in a region of space without the interference of matter, an Anti-matter star should be able to form, fuse all the way down to Anti-iron, build up a large enough core, go supernova and keep fusing into heavier elements.

I just need a simple yes or no answer or a source explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

In short: maybe

All indications to date are that anti-matter behaves exactly like ordinary matter, so anti-hydrogen will fuse. In an anti-star, that should eventually eventually produce either an anti- red giant or an anti-supernova.

However, that last sentence assumes that anti-matter also behaves the same with respect to gravity. Some scientists have doubts about that (have a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter)), so the answer is still out.

Comment: Given that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium#Anti-deuterium is known for 50 years, your answer "_maybe_" seemed quite weak. I was then surprised to find out from http://agenda.infn.it/getFile.py/access?contribId=2&resId=0&materialId=slides&confId=5913 (p.9) that the uncertainty even of recent mass measurements seems too large to claim that "2 anti-protons can fuse to anti-deuterium, leaving an electron and anti-neutrino". However, there are of course strong indications for anti-matter behaving sufficiently similar like matter to expect fusion; cmp. http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3312